# What is the use of `set` keyword during property declaration in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I saw this line of code in one of the classes from a project at work.

```swift
static private(set) var shared = UserPreferences()
```

I dont understand the use of `(set)` keyword in the above declaration. Tried normal googling but was unable to find anything useful. Can someone kindly explain its use? Thanks!

Comment: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AccessControl.html Under 'Getters and Setters'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a `set` keyword but a `private(set)` keyword.

This makes the var accessible as `internal` but constricts the write (set) access to `private`.

So this value can only be set from inside the type it is defined in. But can be read from anywhere in the module that the type is defined in.

You can read more about this here... https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AccessControl.html#ID17